# Postman error "Your team updated to Postman v7.0, you must also update to v7.0 by going to > Settings > Update"

Tags: postman

Installed Postman on ubuntu 18.04 using snap but I am getting this error

`Your team updated to Postman v7.0. To keep your collections and workspaces in sync with your team, you must also update to v7.0 by going to > Settings > Update`

but there is no option to update in settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using ubuntu snap then you have to change channel of postman to candidate

```
sudo snap switch --channel=candidate postman
sudo snap refresh postman
```

then relaunch postman and you will be able to sync data.